# Report Boxes with Condition

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that contains the stores, the condition of open or closed and the date; I am asked to show a report showing all the stores and that those that are open are highlighted from those that are closed.

These will be segmented by date.

I am looking for info to do something similar in the attached image, I would appreciate your support.

Thank you.

[Example of Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp5uD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few KPI cards or a similar visualization to achieve this. Choose the value to be displayed as the store and apply a filter restricting each KPI card to a single store. Then, you can use the Conditional formatting setting in the "Formatting" section to reflect whatever color you choose depending on the store status (Open/Closed). If you need further details regarding this refer to the link:

https://insightsquest.com/2018/05/06/conditional-formatting-for-card-visuals/

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still searching since I tried with Table and the conditionals, but it doesn't help me solve the problem.

Comment: Use KPI Cards not tables